# Facing issues with org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am facing issues with Hibernate mappings. I am using oracle database. Please see the code and please help me in resolving this.

Model classes:

```
package com.model;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="emp")
    public class Employee {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="eno")
        int empid;

        @Column(name="name")
        String name;

        @ManyToOne()
        @JoinColumn(name="deptid",nullable=false)
        Department dept;

        public int getEmpid() {
            return empid;
        }
        public void setEmpid(int empid) {
            this.empid = empid;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Department getDept() {
            return dept;
        }
        public void setDept(Department dept) {
            this.dept = dept;
        }

    }

package com.model;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="dept")
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="deptid")
    int deptid;

    @Column(name="deptname")
    String deptname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="dept")
    Set<Employee> empset;

    public int getDeptid() {
        return deptid;
    }
    public void setDeptid(int deptid) {
        this.deptid = deptid;
    }
    public String getDeptname() {
        return deptname;
    }
    public void setDeptname(String deptname) {
        this.deptname = deptname;
    }
    public Set<Employee> getEmpset() {
        return empset;
    }
    public void setEmpset(Set<Employee> empset) {
        this.empset = empset;
    }
}
```

configuration file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
        <property name="connection.username">user_name</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>

        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

    <mapping class="com.model.Employee"/>
    <mapping class="com.model.Department"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

test class:

```
package com.demo;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.model.Department;
import com.model.Employee;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure();
        SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session sess = sf.openSession();
        Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();

        Department dept1 = new Department();
        dept1.setDeptname("aaa");

        sess.save(dept1);

        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.setName("aaa");
        emp1.setDept(dept1);

        sess.save(emp1);
        tx.commit();
        sess.close();
    }
}
```

db tables structure:
create table emp(eno number(4) primary key,name varchar2(10),deptid number(5) forign key references dept(deptid));

create table emp(deptid number(5) primary key,deptname varchar2(10));

And the error I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at com.demo.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:23)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("VASAVI"."DEPT"."DEPTID")

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:955)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1169)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3368)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Can you please check your db queries for creating tables? Because what you have provided is 2 queries for generating the same table. Where is the query for creating `dept` table?

Comment: Sorry. By mistake I have given the same name here. two tables are there in the db. @RAS

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your persistent classes on MySQL database with my hibernate.properties. Everything works perfect (without any errors). So, I think, you need to recreate your database schema with

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error always appears if you want to insert a row with a value in a column having a unique index or constraint, and the inserted value for this column already exists in an other row.Recreate the db schema.
Change your configuration file

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
```

to

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Comment: Now I am getting a different error: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:XE

Comment: The listener could not find any available service handlers that are appropriate for the client connection.problem on the Oracle server:

http://ora-12519.ora-code.com/

Comment: also verify the number of connection in oracle configuration.

Comment: Also look in to this link,it might help you https://community.oracle.com/thread/376670?start=0&tstart=0